# How to enable debug logs in the Camunda 7 docker image?

Tags: docker, camunda

In the Camunda 7 Platform Job executor troubleshooting guide https://camunda.com/blog/2019/10/job-executor-what-is-going-on-in-my-process-engine/ debugging logging is supposed to be turned on for a few subsystems:

> Set the loggers org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.JobEntity, org.camunda.bpm.engine.jobexecutor, org.camunda.bpm.engine.cmd to DEBUG. This will produce output as follows:

How can I turn on these debugging log options in the default Camunda 7 Docker container?

Answer (score 0):

The Camunda 7 container has a configuration file that controls the logging verbosity. It is located in `/camunda/conf/logging.properties` inside the container.

To turn on logging for the mentioned systems add the following lines to the end of the `logging.properties` file:

```
org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.JobEntity.level = FINE
org.camunda.bpm.engine.jobexecutor.level = FINE
org.camunda.bpm.engine.cm.level = FINE
```

Notice that `.level` needs to be added to the end of the logger name and that the equivalent of `DEBUG` logging level in this case is `FINE`.

To use the new logging config file in a container it can either be added to the image in a dockerfile or mounted in docker compose with:

```
    volumes:
      - ./logging.properties:/camunda/conf/logging.properties:ro
```